# How to prove the following calculus theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $ f:A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function which is defined in some punctured neighborhood of $ x_0 $. Then $ \lim_{x\to x_{0}}f\left(x\right)=L $ if and only if, for any path $ \gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $ such that $ \lim_{t\to1^{-}}\gamma\left(t\right)=x_{0} $ and  $ \forall t\in[0,1]\thinspace\thinspace:\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\gamma\left(t\right)\neq x_{0} $ we have $ \lim_{t\to1^{-}}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)=L $.

If I know that $ \lim_{x\to x_{0}}f\left(x\right)=L $, then its not hard to prove that for any path $ \gamma $ we have $ \lim_{t\to1^{-}}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)=L $.

Im struggling with the other direction. Assume for any path $ \gamma(t) $ as described in the theorem we have $ \lim_{t\to1^{-}}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)=L $. How can I show that the limit of $ f $ is $ L $ ?

Also, does this mean that I could choose whatever path I want in order to check if the limit exists? for example, say I have the function $ f\left(x,y\right) $ and I want to check its limit at $(0,0)$. If I'll choose the paths:

$ \gamma_{1}\left(t\right)=\left(t^{2}-1,t\sin\left(t-1\right)\right),\thinspace\thinspace\gamma_{2}\left(t\right)=\left(\ln\left(t\right),\sqrt{\left(1-t\right)}\right) $

and I'll get that one of the limits $ \lim_{t\to1^{-}}f\left(\gamma_{1}\left(t\right)\right) $ or $ \lim_{t\to1^{-}}f\left(\gamma_{2}\left(t\right)\right) $ does not exist, or they both exist but $ \lim_{t\to1^{-}}f\left(\gamma_{1}\left(t\right)\right)\neq\lim_{t\to1^{-}}f\left(\gamma_{2}\left(t\right)\right) $.

Does this mean that $ \lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(0,0\right)}f\left(x,y\right) $ does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any sequence $x_i$ tending to $x_0$ you can construct a path $\gamma $ such that $\gamma(1-\frac 1 i)=x_i$ for all $i$ and $\gamma (1)=x_0$. Just join the points by line segments. Hence, $f(x_i)=f(\gamma (1-\frac 1  i)) \to f(\gamma (1))=f(x_0)$ as $ i \to \infty$.

If the limit along some path does not exist or it exists but it is not $L$ then we can assert that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=L$ is false. If yo want to prove that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=L$ is  true then you will have to prove that the limit is $L$ **along every path ending at $x_0$**.

Comment: Oh you used Heine's definition for the limit, I see. What about my other question? can you tell if my interpretation to the theorem is correct?

Comment: I thought about this too, but it assumes that $A$ contains some ball centered at $x_0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OP states that $f$ is defined in some punctured disk around $x_0$.

Comment: Sure. I missed that.

Comment: @FreeZe I have edited my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So my examples are correct? if for those 2 pathes the limit is not the same then there is no limit?

Comment: @FreeZe Sure. Your examples of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ work fine.